# word frequency from file using partial match

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a text file like this:

```
tom
and
jerry
went
to
america
and
england
```

I want to get the frequency of each word.

When I tried the following command

```
cat test.txt |sort|uniq -c
```

I got the following output

```
   1 america
   2 and
   1 england
   1 jerry
   1 to
   1 tom
   1 went
```

But I need partial matches too. ie, the word `to` present in the word `tom`. So my expected word count of `to` is 2. Is it possible using `unix` commands?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, but it isn't very elegant:

```
$ sort -u file | while IFS= read -r word; do 
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "$word" "$(grep -cFe "$word" file)"; 
    done
america 1
and 3
england 1
jerry   1
to  2
tom 1
went    1
```

Answer (score 3):

An `awk` approach:

```
awk '
  !x {c[$0]; next}
  {for (i in c) if (index($0, i)) c[i]++}
  END{for (i in c) print c[i]"\t"i}' file x=1 file | sort -k1rn
```

Which on your input give

```
3       and
2       to
1       america
1       england
1       jerry
1       tom
1       went
```

We process the input in two passes. In the first pass, we record the list of distinct words as the keys of the `c` hash table.

In the second pass, for each line in the file, we loop over all the keys in `c` and increment the corresponding value if the key is found in the line.

The list of distinct words in the file ends up being stored in memory. If those are English words, it shouldn't be a problem as there are fewer and 200,000 distinct words in the English language.

Comment: thank you. this command works. if i run this command against a large file around 30gb, will a machine of 8gb ram handle that?

Comment: @TweetMan depends how many unique words there are. It stores all unique words in memory.

Comment: Hmm. then that would be a problem. it may crash the system.

Comment: Awk isn't safe with large files and it bogs down. You may want to look into loading the data into a SQL database and querying it that way.

Comment: @A.Danischewski, awk as a language has no issue with large files. There are many implementations of an interpreter for that language. Could you please be more specific as to which implementation can't handle large files and how? How would using a SQL database help here?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Awk does have issues with large files. It looks great and quick because everything is loaded into memory (it uses hashing and btrees). Any version of awk that I know of will break on a sufficiently large file and before it breaks it will be using a lot of memory. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459426/awk-vs-mysql-for-data-aggregation

Answer (score 2):

This won't crash the system but it may take a long time to run, since it parses the input multiple times.  Assuming the input file is called "in":

```
sort -u < in | while read w
do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" `grep -c "$w" in` "$w"
done
```

which on your input got me:

```
1       america
3       and
1       england
1       jerry
2       to
1       tom
1       went
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if the partial matches are to be anchored to the beginning of the line.
Assuming the answer is yes, what *might* speed things up here is the use of binary search via the venerable `look` command.
Of course `look` needs that its input file be sorted.
Therefore, first create a sorted version of the original file

```
 sort file > file.sorted
```

Then loop through the original file, `look`ing up one word at a time against the sorted file.

```
while read -r word; do 
    printf "%s %d\n" "$word" "$(look -b "$word" file.sorted | wc -l)"; 
done <file
```

Some systems don't need the `-b` flag to be passed to `look` to force a binary search.
Disk caching of the sorted file could help speed things up even further